# Making Hibernate Spatial DWITHIN compatible with both H2GIS and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial, h2gis

I have following:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Feature f WHERE DWITHIN(f.geometry, :centre, :range, true) = TRUE")
```

DWITHIN is hibernate spatial function [explained here](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/01-overview/).

```
boolean dwithin(Geometry, Geometry, double) Returns true if the geometries are within the specified 
distance of one another
```

In my query above I pass 4 parameters. Internally hibernate spatial maps it to postgis [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) which has 2 variants. If I don't pass fourth parameter, first variant is considered  which takes 3rd parameter as SRID degree range and not distance. If I pass fourth parameter, third parameter is considered as distance in meters.

But for H2GIS(OrbisGIS), there is only a single [variant](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_DWithin/) which takes 3 parameters, and it always takes 3rd parameter as distance.

For above query to work with both, I would need to get rid of fourth parameter, in which case PostGIS version would start treating 3rd parameter as SRID degree range while I want it to be treated as distance in meters.

This is my understanding of the issue.

Am I right here? If yes, how can I make it work for both, accepting 3rd parameter as distance in meters.

Comment: I have deleted original question, and updated this one with details.

Comment: I don't understand your question, Hibernate use GeoDB not H2GIS